# Python app - Various import errors between Langchain and other dependencies

Tags: import, pip, openai-api, langchain

I am trying to create a web research agent in Python based on an open-source GitHub repo and am going in circles trying to update and/or deprecate Langchain and other dependencies to clear errors.

Originally I was getting an import error when trying to do:

```
from langchain.agents import create_openai_functions_agent

I cleared that error by upgrading Langchain to the latest version. But when I did that, I now get a whole slew of new errors:

PS C:\Users\AM\Desktop\My Code\GH\researcher-gpt> python app2.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\AM\Desktop\My Code\GH\researcher-gpt\app2.py", line 6, in
from langchain_contrib.prompts import ChainedPromptTemplate
File "C:\Users\AM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\langchain_contrib\prompts_init_.py", line 3, in
from .chained import ChainedPromptTemplate
File "C:\Users\AM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\langchain_contrib\prompts\chained.py", line 13, in
from langchain_contrib.utils import f_join, safe_inputs
File "C:\Users\AM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\langchain_contrib\utils_init_.py", line 5, in
from .llm import call_llm
File "C:\Users\AM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\langchain_contrib\utils\llm.py", line 7, in
from langchain.schema import BaseLanguageModel, PromptValue
ImportError: cannot import name 'BaseLanguageModel' from 'langchain.schema' (C:\Users\AM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\langchain\schema_init_.py)
```

I then followed instructions from various similar user issues on Github by upgrading and/or deprecating various packages. Each time, I manage to clear some errors but then introduce new ones.

For example, I tried deprecating to versions like:

```
pip install llama-index==0.5.6
pip install langchain==0.0.148
```

And while that clears some of the import errors, it breaks other code such as `import create_openai_functions_agent`

It would be nice if I could get everything to work using the latest version of Langchain and not have to go backwards.

Below are all my CURRENT installs and below that is my actual code. ANY HELP MUCH APPRECIATED!!

```
C:\Users\AM>pip freeze
aiohttp==3.9.1
aiosignal==1.3.1
annotated-types==0.6.0
anyio==4.2.0
attrs==23.2.0
beautifulsoup4==4.12.2
certifi==2023.11.17
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
click==8.1.7
colorama==0.4.6
dataclasses-json==0.5.14
distro==1.9.0
executing==2.0.1
fastapi==0.108.0
frozenlist==1.4.1
fsspec==2023.12.2
fvalues==0.0.3
gpt-index==0.8.42
greenlet==3.0.3
h11==0.14.0
httpcore==1.0.2
httpx==0.26.0
idna==3.6
joblib==1.3.2
jsonpatch==1.33
jsonpointer==2.4
langchain==0.1.0
langchain-community==0.0.11
langchain-contrib==0.0.4
langchain-core==0.1.8
langchain-openai==0.0.2
langsmith==0.0.79
llama_index==0.5.6
marshmallow==3.20.1
multidict==6.0.4
mypy-extensions==1.0.0
nest-asyncio==1.5.8
nltk==3.8.1
numexpr==2.8.8
numpy==1.26.3
openai==1.7.0
openapi-schema-pydantic==1.2.4
packaging==23.2
pandas==2.1.4
pexpect==4.9.0
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pydantic==1.10.8
pydantic_core==2.14.6
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==1.0.0
pytz==2023.3.post1
PyYAML==6.0.1
regex==2023.12.25
requests==2.31.0
setuptools==69.0.3
simple-term-menu==1.6.4
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.3.0
soupsieve==2.5
SQLAlchemy==2.0.25
starlette==0.32.0.post1
tenacity==8.2.3
tiktoken==0.5.2
tqdm==4.66.1
typing-inspect==0.9.0
typing_extensions==4.9.0
tzdata==2023.4
urllib3==1.26.18
yarl==1.9.4

C:\Users\AM>python --version
Python 3.12.1
```

START OF APPLICATION BELOW, DEVELOPING ON WINDOWS 10 PC:

```
import os
import json
import requests
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain_contrib.prompts import ChainedPromptTemplate
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor, create_openai_functions_agent
from langchain.tools import BaseTool
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate, MessagesPlaceholder
from langchain.memory import ConversationSummaryBufferMemory
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.chains import LLMSummarizationCheckerChain
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fastapi import FastAPI

load_dotenv()
browserless_api_key = os.getenv("BROWSERLESS_API_KEY")
serper_api_key = os.getenv("SERP_API_KEY")

....
```

Comment: Yes, I am always dealing with this dependency problems even if I follow the the tutorials in Llama and Langchain official webpages and with fresh virtualenvironment